# .NET application crashes when upload big file

Tags: c#, .net, file, google-chrome, upload

I have a problem with a .NET application. When I'm trying to upload big files (meaning files larger than 30-40 MB) Chrome crashes ("Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this page"). Actually, web page crashes when I upload a file, even though I don't press any button after that. It's important to mention that the problem disappears when I run the application on Mozzila. Thanks!

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<Request.Files.Count;i++)
                    {
                        var file = Request.Files[i];
                        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            logService.Write(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/wwwroot/contents/"), fileName));
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/wwwroot/contents/"), fileName);
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                            training.Contents.Add(new Data.Data.Content() { DisplayName = fileName, Id = Guid.NewGuid(), JoinDate = DateTime.Now, Path = "/wwwroot/contents/" +  fileName, TrainingId = training.Id });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    logService.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked the console and network area of the chrome debugger?

Comment: For people to be able to help, they are going to need a question that is a bit more specific and probably see some code of some sort

Comment: What method are you using to upload files?

Comment: I edited the post adding the code.

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Comment: Check also web server settings for limitation on uploads.